# How are $LOAD_PATH and $: different?

Tags: ruby, load-path

I needed to know what was in my Ruby load path, so I did this:

```
$ ruby -e "puts $LOAD_PATH"
```

It didn't print anything out, which I **didn't** expect.  So I tried this:

```
$ ruby -e "puts $:"
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/i486-linux
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/i386-linux
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i486-linux
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i486-linux
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-linux
.
```

Why does the second one give me the expected output and the first one doesn't?  Shouldn't they be the same?  I just tried it in `irb`, and I got the results I expected.

This is my Ruby version, in case it makes a difference:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i486-linux]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not.  Try running this command:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts $LOAD_PATH'
```

which doesn't make shell expand `$LOAD_PATH` due to use of `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: Gah!  That makes perfect sense.  I guess this is the first time I've used a global when doing `ruby -e`.  :)